# can we use cloudwatch events on s3 object with serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

I want to know if we can create a cloudwatch event that triggered on S3 bucket every time that a change occurs on S3. For example, if a file is uploaded on s3 we recieve an email.
I am using serverless framework, i found on the serverless documentation only stuff related to ec2, but not much things on s3. So please if anyone knows how to use cloudwatch with s3 i am all ears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/

e.g.

```
functions:
  emailOnUpload:
    handler: email.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: photos
          event: s3: ObjectCreated:*
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i have already try this, but it did not work

Comment: there is no error, but i am not getting email, don't know what is wrong